# How do I get Table from Vector layers for use with joinattributestable

Tags: pyqgis, vector, attribute-joins, table

I am attempting to run:

`processing.runandload('qgis:joinattributestable', layer1, layer2, 'id', 'id', None)`

To join my tables and output to a temporary viewing layer.

layer1 and layer2 are both Spatialite imports. They are vector type objects within QGIS.

joinattributestable specifies the following inputs:

```
ALGORITHM: Join attributes table
    INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
    INPUT_LAYER_2 <ParameterTable>
    TABLE_FIELD <parameters from INPUT_LAYER>
    TABLE_FIELD_2 <parameters from INPUT_LAYER_2>
    OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>
```

How can I get ParameterTable from my Vector object?

Answer (score 2):

To convert layer object to table try this:

```
myCSV = 'C:/Temp/myCSV.csv' # change path or .csv file name if needed
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer2, myCSV, "utf-8", None, "CSV")
result = processing.runandload('qgis:joinattributestable', layer1, myCSV, 'id', 'id', None)
memoryLayer = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT']) # this create the object layer
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I _cannot run_ the algorithm because layer2 as third argument is invalid. It's a vector. Not a table. I need to turn it into a table.

Comment: Updated my answer